# Is there any issue with having spaces in an HTML checkboxes value attribute?

Tags: html, checkbox

Been wondering if its possible to include spaces within a checkboxes value attribute.

From my own testing it appears perfectly possible but after some Googling I can't see anything which confirms or denies this.

Thought I would ask on here incase any of you guys have a definitive answer as I wouldn't be surprised if its treated differently by different browsers etc etc

Comment: can you write an example?

Comment: This is potentially an easy to answer question, but, why are you including spaces? What happens with the values?

Comment: Since it's "value" it shouldn't be any problem to put there even whole utf nowaydays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, There's no problem having spaces on value attributes for checkboxes.

Reference: W3C - [The value attribute is String type](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox.attrs.value)

Answer (score 1):

It's both possible and valid, [the `value` attribute simply expects a CDATA value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT), but keep in mind that

> User agents may ignore leading and trailing white space in CDATA attribute values